# how to send and accept friend request using Signal R

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I managed to create a chat application using SignalR and Asp.NET.
My next objective is to send and accept friend request.

Could anyone suggest some good sites/forums where I can get help regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about this from a system design standpoint prior to approaching a solution directly with ASP.NET and SignalR.  Some of the things you need to consider and decide on are:

How will one user be associated to another user in order to create a friendship? (ex: new table to group two users)

How should friend requests be made?

How will friend request denials work?

Once you start brainstorming on how you would want this all to work, you can then build it out on the server side prior to ever getting into SignalR.  Assure all areas of functionality work appropriately and then you can expose these method calls to your clients front-end through SignalR.

The key is to break down each part of the process into components and working on it one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

to send friend request to specific user use hub method

```
Clients.Client(toConnectTo).sendRequest(currentname+" SentYouFriendRequest");
```

and call it on client

```
chat.client.sendRequest = function (msg) {
  $('#sentmsg').append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
};
```